# JqTouch - Detect trigger for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

Yet another problem I'm having w/ jqTouch...
I'm trying to detect what element was clicked to trigger an animation so that I can pass parameters from the clicked item to the subsequent page.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="places">
 <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Places</h1>
  <a class="back" href="#">Back</a>
    </div>
 <ul>
  <li id="1"><a href="#singleplace">Place 1</a></li>
  <li id="2"><a href="#singleplace">Place 2</a></li>
  <li id="3"><a href="#singleplace">Place 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="singleplace">
 <div class="toolbar">
        <h1></h1>
  <a class="back" href="#">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on any of the list items in #places, I'm able to slide over to #singleplace just fine, but I'm trying to detect which element was clicked so that I can pass parameters into the #singleplace div. My javascript is:

```
var placeID;
$('#places a').live('mouseup',function(){
 $('#singleplace h1').html($(this).text())
 placeID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
})
```

I've tried several alternatives to the $(el).live('event', fn()) approach including:

```
$('#places a').live('click',fn()...
$('#places a').live('mouseup',fn()...
$('#places a').live('tap',fn()...
$('#places a').tap(fn()...
```

None of which seem to work. Is there a better way I could be handling this? 
I noticed on jqTouch's issues page, there is this: http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=91
which may be part of the problem...

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to pass info from which list item was clicked, you could attach an `onClick="function(event)"` to the items...

```
<li><a id="1" title="first" onClick="send(event)" href="#singleplace">Place 1</a></li>
```

then in the js...

```
function send(event) {
    x=event.target;
}
```

where `x.id=='1' x.title==first & x.text=='Place 1'`

hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

- Use `tap(function()...)` instead of `live('click',function()...)`
- Use `jQT.goTo('#singleplace', 'slide');`
- use `return false;`

```
    var placeID;  
    $('#places a').tap(function(){  
     $('#singleplace h1').html($(this).text());  
     placeID = $(this).parent().attr('id');  
     jQT.goTo('#singleplace', 'slide');     
     return false; 
    });
```

This works for me, even in Firefox and Safari, not only in mobile safari.

**Some additional information:**
There seems to be a problem with the live event in JQTouch: http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=165

Let me know if this also works for you.